Socket.io behind a Nginx reverse proxy not working
I am serving my front-end static files with Nginx as follows.
server {                                                                        
        server_name  <my_domain>;                                          
                                                                                    
        root /usr/share/nginx/myproject/dist;                                  
        index index.htm index.html;                                                 
                                                                                    
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;                  
        error_log /var/log/nginx/host.error.log notice;                    
                                                                                    
        location /socket.io/ {                                                      
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;              
          proxy_set_header Host $host;                                              
                                                                                    
          proxy_pass https://localhost:8000;                                         
                                                                                    
          proxy_http_version 1.1;                                                   
          proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;                                   
          proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";                                    
         }         

        location / {                                                                
             try_files $uri $uri/ =404;                                              
         }

        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot                                        
        ssl_certificate  # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot       
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot         
    }


When I visit the domain address, I can see the front-end just fine but it is not making any websocket connections with the backend. There is no error whatsoever and the requests are only for the front-end contents.
My server code looks like this.
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
import http from 'http';
import https from 'https';
import express from "express";
import { Server } from 'socket.io';
import cors from "cors";

const app = express();
app.use(cors);

let server;
if (process.env.NODE_ENV == "development") {
    server = http.createServer(app);
} else {
    server = https.createServer({
        cert: readFileSync("/etc/letsencrypt/live/<my_domain>/cert.pem", "utf8"),
        key: readFileSync("/etc/letsencrypt/live/<my_domain>/privkey.pem", "utf8"),
        ca: readFileSync("/etc/letsencrypt/live/<my_domain>/chain.pem", "utf8"),
    }, app);
}
let origin;
if (process.env.NODE_ENV == "development") {
    origin = "http://localhost:5173";
} else {
    origin = "http://<domain_name>";
}
const io = new Server(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: "*",
        methods: ["GET", "POST"]
    },
});


io.on('connection', (sock) => {
    sock.on('disconnect', (sock_id) => {
        console.log('user disconnected.')
    })

});

server.on('error', (err) => console.error(err));

server.listen(8000, () => {
    console.log('server is ready on 8000');
})

The client-side uses the socket object, which is exported as follows, in a single component.
import { io, Socket } from "socket.io-client";
import { ServerToClientEvents, ClientToServerEvents } from "./types";

let socket: Socket<ServerToClientEvents, ClientToServerEvents>;
if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development') {
    socket = io("http://localhost:8000",);
} else {
    socket = io(
        "https://<my_domain>/", { transports: ["websockets"], });
}

export default socket;


Of course I have tested in development but it is just not working on my VPS host. I have tried custom paths as mentioned on socket.io documentations.
I have tried both http and https server for my express backend.
I have tried both localhost and 127.0.0.1 on my nginx configurations.
I have tried multiple ports for the server.

I fixed it by removing { transports: ["websockets"] } from the client side and on the server side I removed methods option in CORS and make the origin point to my domain.
